# Automated soft credits based on rules

Tags: contributions, households, soft-credit

Since I started using CiviCRM about 5 years ago I've thought one of the biggest problem areas was related to tracking and searching for contributions based on household, which is generally how non-profit contributions should be tracked. It's been the source of many struggles at 2 or 3 orgs I have been associated with during this time.

Soft credits have helped to some degree, but require consistent and mistake-free work. A possibly very useful solution occurred to me last night - what if any time an individual makes a contribution it automatically soft-credited the household they are a member of?

Ideally it could be turned off and on and have the ability to control based on financial type.

Thoughts?

Comment: This is great! Thank you. I will install the extension and see if it will work for us. I like the flexibility of rules and actions, but sounds like it's not necessary to pursue for this use case.

Comment: Not sure if "which is generally how non-profit contributions should be tracked" is that much of a general true-ism

Comment: Who doesn't track contributions by household? Would you consider a husband a non-contributor if his wife is the one who actually used her credit card for the contribution? Or would you ask one member of a household for $100 in a given fundraising campaign even if the other member regularly gives $10,000? I have worked at several non-profits and none didn't try track donations by family.

Comment: It's important to treat a family as one entity for fundraising purposes... it is the norm.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an extension that automatically creates a soft credit. I use it with my org and it works great. I'm running 4.7.2 with drupal 7.

https://github.com/PalanteJon/coop.palantetech.module.automaticsoftcredit

Answer (score 2):

It is a great idea. Using [CiviRules](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules), you could get a good bit of the way there out of the box.  To set the soft credit though, you would need to (or pay someone to) [write some code](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviRules+-+how+to+make+your+own) -- you'd have to [code the **CiviRule action**](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/How+to+Create+Your+Own+Action).

For the **formula**, you'd set the trigger to "Contribution is added."

For the **conditions**, you could have a couple:

- "Contribution is (not) of financial type ..." and you could set the type.
- "Contact (not) in group" and you'd select a Smart group you created for people who are in a household (if you have contacts who are *not* in a household, you would need this check in the rules).

For the **action**, you would need to code it such that a soft credit is created for the household that is related to the contact that added the contribution.  Or if you wanted to get a bit more flexible with it, you could code it such that the user could select the relationship that determines the soft credit.

CiviRules allows you to enable/disable a Rule as you see fit.

Comment: Well, frTommy's solution (posted around the same time) looks like the better answer, but I'll leave this here for people who want to go the CiviRules route.